# como realizar una consultas SELECT multi-tabla cuando los variables de las tablas a consultar son de tipos de datos diferentes

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Tengo consulta que quiero hacer desde mi programa en c# a sql, basicamente tengo dos variables:

- idCliente string
- idSede int

**En la BBDD en sus respectivas tablas dichos datos son del mismo tipo**

Dichos datos están en dos tablas diferentes en sql server
pasa que necesito hacer una consulta doble pero no puedo usar join ya que dichos datos son de tipos diferentes mi pregunta es como podria adaptar dicha consulta a lo que necesito

```
 string consulta = "SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE IdCliente ='"+idCliente+"'"+ "AND WHERE Sede idSede ='"+idSede;
```

esta es la consulta que intento hacer, no puedo cambiar los tipo de datos de mi basa de datos, debo apegarme a el formato.

mi duda es  si pueden ayudarme hacer la consulta correctamente ?

Básicamente lo que intento hacer, es decir, que se seleccionaran todos los campos de la tabla Clientes siempre que IDCliente sea igual al idCliente que saco de mi programa y además de eso, se cumpla también que en la tabla sedes que el elemento idSede sea igual al dato que saco del programa idSede pero no logro hacerlo correctamente

Comment: No comprendo bien, en la bbdd los datos son string e int también?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, la consulta está mal, tienes una comilla simple de apertura en idSede, pero no de cierre.

```
SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE IdCliente ='"+idCliente+"'"+ "AND WHERE Sede idSede ='"+idSede
..............................................................^^^^^.^^^^.........^
```

Aparte solo puedes tener una clausula WHERE y no puedes realizar la llamada a otra tabla de esta manera, deberías generar una subquery.

> no puedo usar join ya que dichos datos son de tipos diferentes

¿Por qué no? El tipo siempre lo puedes convertir al formato que necesites, puedes usar [`CAST` y `CONVERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) en tu query:

```
CAST(elem AS INT)
CONVERT(INT, elem)
```

Parece que has escrito la query sin ni siquiera probarla, puedes hacerlo desde el [manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Suponiendo que tienes vinculados cliente y sede mediante una FOREING KEY la query sería:

```
string consulta = @"SELECT cli.*, se.* FROM Cliente cli
INNER JOIN Sede se ON cli.idSede = se.IdSede
WHERE cli.IdCliente = CAST("+idCliente+" AS int)";
```

Comment: "no puedes realizar la llamada a otra tabla en ella."ehhh.. no me suena cierto eso... (podrias hacer exist a otra tabla)...

Comment: cierto, en una subquery, me referia a como lo tiene

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta @Nicolas Oñate